# Mailers not working following upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

We have recently upgraded form Rails 3.0 to rails 3.2. At the same time we have upgraded from ruby 1.9.3 to Ruby 2.1.5. We are snagging all kinds of things but the one thing that is baffling me is the email, which was working fine before but is now simply not sending. Is there something amiss with the code below?

**Controller code**

```
def send_welcome
  UserNotifier.new_user_welcome(user).deliver
  ...
end
```

**Notifier code**

```
class EmployeeNotifier < ActionMailer::Base

def setup_email(to, subject, from = Saas::Config.from_email)
  @sent_on = Time.zone.now
  @subject = subject
  @recipients = to.respond_to?(:email) ? to.email : to
  @from = from.respond_to?(:email) ? from.email : from
end

def new_user_welcome(user)
  @user = user
  setup_email(user.email,"Welcome!")
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the call to `mail` inside the mailer action.

```
def my_email
  # ...

  mail  to: "recipient",
        subject: "..."
end
```

In your case

```
def setup_email(...)
  # ...

  mail  to: @recipients,
        from: @from,
        subject: @subject,
end
```